# Populating a form from a table of results php

Tags: php, html

I have a simple form that stores info into a database (index.html) and a script to show its results (show.php) which is just a query executed with a while statement to I can generate rows of results for a table.

I added two images in one of the columnos for edition and printing, but I don't have any idea on how to bring the results of that specific row back to index.html for edition/updating the info. I want to populate that form so I can continue working over the updating form.

I'll paste just the code where I do the while statement:

```php
while ($colum = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
    echo "<tr>";    
    echo "<td><h6> <img src='editar.png'>  <span hidden style='background:moccasin'>". $colum['id']."</span> </img> <img src='impresora.png'></img></td></h6>";
    echo "<td><h6>" . $colum['nombre']. "</td></h6>";
    echo "<td><h6>" . $colum['apellido_paterno']. "</td></h6>";    
    echo "<td><h6>" . $colum['apellido_materno']. "</td></h6>";
    echo "<td><h6>" . $colum['grupo']. "</td></h6>";
    echo "<td><h6>" . $colum['tutor']. "</td></h6>";
    echo "<td><h6>" . $colum['domicilio']. "</td></h6>";
    echo "<td><h6>" . $colum['telefono1']. "</td></h6>";
    echo "<td><h6>" . $colum['telefono2']. "</td></h6>";
    echo "<td><h6>" . $colum['nee']. "</td></h6>";
    echo "<td><h6>" . $colum['discapacidad']. "</td></h6>";
    echo "<td><h6>" . $colum['leer']. "</td></h6>";
    echo "<td><h6>" . $colum['escribir']. "</td></h6>";
    echo "<td><h6>" . $colum['historial']. "</td></h6>";
    echo "<td><h6>" . $colum['enfermedad']. "</td></h6>";
    echo "<td><h6>" . $colum['medicamento']. "</td></h6>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

So, each one of those echos belong to each one of the inputs I want to populate back in the form (they have the exact same name). Also, it might sound silly but I want the simplest possible solution, since this is not for any company, just for personal use so I could put security aside on this.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit 1: I tried using the URL format to fill the inputs but doesn't work like this:
index.php?nombre=JustAName

These is an example of how my inputs look in index.php:

```html
<form action="registrar2.php" method="post" class="needs-validation" name="procesar"  novalidate onsubmit="return validarform()">  

<div class="row">  
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-xs-12">  
       <div class="form-group mb-2">  
           <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-text">Nombre del Alumno:</span>
              <input type="text" aria-label="First name" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control" required>
                 <div class="invalid-feedback">Ingresar nombre.  
                 </div>                                            
           </div>
                                        
       </div>  
   </div>
<!-- SOME OTHER INPUTS ARE BELOW TOO --> 
</form>
```

Comment: Wrap the image in a hyperlink which goes to your editing page, and passes the ID of the item as a URL query parameter e.g. `/edit.php?id=1`

Comment: @ADyson I've tried that and for some reason it doesn't fill up the inputs. I'll edit the post so you can see how my inputs look.

Comment: Well you'd need some PHP code to get the ID from the URL (it'll be in the $_GET array), get the data from the database and populate it into the HTML fields in the right place. It's not auto-magical! It seems like a tutorial or book on some basics of PHP web applications might do you good, because this is all fairly standard stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from @Adyson is correct.

PHP for the top of that page.

```
    include "elements/connect.php"; //Get connection data.

    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tableName` WHERE `ID`='".$_GET['id']."'";
       //Print results into a VAR to call on
       $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
       $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
       //Add the columns that are for the matching row
       $count = $row;
    
       $varName = $row['rowName'];
    
    } else {
       //No one should access the edit page, unless they are editing.
       header('Location: index.php');
       exit;
    }
    
    if($_GET['send']==="y"){
       $sql2 = "UPDATE `tableName` SET `rowName`='".$_POST['updatedVal']."' WHERE `ID`='".$_POST['hidID']."'";
       mysqli_query($conn,$sql2)
    }
```

HTML form with values populated:

```
<form action="?send=y" method="post">
<input name="updatedVal" type="text" value="<?php echo $varName; ?>" placeholder="Enter name" required/>
<input name="hidID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>">
<button type="submit">Update data</button>
```